# C# and Unity. Take pictures while rotating the camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, screenshot

So I have the Screenshot (Tool) working and the camera rotation working. By themselves.
I would like to take a picture maybe every second as the camera is rotating automatically.
I don't know enough about C# to decipher what to extract from the Screenshot class. Also I don't know if I can call the class from my camera rotation class.

Thanks.

Here are the 2 classes.

Screenshot tool.

```
//C# Example
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;


[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class Screenshot : EditorWindow
{

    int resWidth = Screen.width*4; 
    int resHeight = Screen.height*4;

    public Camera myCamera;
    int scale = 1;

    string path = "";
    bool showPreview = true;
    RenderTexture renderTexture;

    bool isTransparent = false;

    // Add menu item named "My Window" to the Window menu
    [MenuItem("Tools/Screenshot/Instant High-Res Screenshot")]
    public static void ShowWindow()
    {
        //Show existing window instance. If one doesn't exist, make one.
        EditorWindow editorWindow = EditorWindow.GetWindow(typeof(Screenshot));
        editorWindow.autoRepaintOnSceneChange = true;
        editorWindow.Show();
        editorWindow.title = "Screenshot";
    }

    float lastTime;


    void OnGUI()
    {
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField ("Resolution", EditorStyles.boldLabel);
        resWidth = EditorGUILayout.IntField ("Width", resWidth);
        resHeight = EditorGUILayout.IntField ("Height", resHeight);

        EditorGUILayout.Space();

        scale = EditorGUILayout.IntSlider ("Scale", scale, 1, 15);

        EditorGUILayout.HelpBox("The default mode of screenshot is crop - so choose a proper width and height. The scale is a factor " +
            "to multiply or enlarge the renders without loosing quality.",MessageType.None);


        EditorGUILayout.Space();


        GUILayout.Label ("Save Path", EditorStyles.boldLabel);

        EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        EditorGUILayout.TextField(path,GUILayout.ExpandWidth(false));
        if(GUILayout.Button("Browse",GUILayout.ExpandWidth(false)))
            path = EditorUtility.SaveFolderPanel("Path to Save Images",path,Application.dataPath);

        EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();

        EditorGUILayout.HelpBox("Choose the folder in which to save the screenshots ",MessageType.None);
        EditorGUILayout.Space();



        //isTransparent = EditorGUILayout.Toggle(isTransparent,"Transparent Background");



        GUILayout.Label ("Select Camera", EditorStyles.boldLabel);


        myCamera = EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(myCamera, typeof(Camera), true,null) as Camera;


        if(myCamera == null)
        {
            myCamera = Camera.main;
        }

        isTransparent = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Transparent Background", isTransparent);


        EditorGUILayout.HelpBox("Choose the camera of which to capture the render. You can make the background transparent using the transparency option.",MessageType.None);

        EditorGUILayout.Space();
        EditorGUILayout.BeginVertical();
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField ("Default Options", EditorStyles.boldLabel);


        if(GUILayout.Button("Set To Screen Size"))
        {
            resHeight = (int)Handles.GetMainGameViewSize().y;
            resWidth = (int)Handles.GetMainGameViewSize().x;

        }


        if(GUILayout.Button("Default Size"))
        {
            resHeight = 1440;
            resWidth = 2560;
            scale = 1;
        }



        EditorGUILayout.EndVertical();

        EditorGUILayout.Space();
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField ("Screenshot will be taken at " + resWidth*scale + " x " + resHeight*scale + " px", EditorStyles.boldLabel);

        if(GUILayout.Button("Take Screenshot",GUILayout.MinHeight(60)))
        {
            if(path == "")
            {
                path = EditorUtility.SaveFolderPanel("Path to Save Images",path,Application.dataPath);
                Debug.Log("Path Set");
                TakeHiResShot();
            }
            else
            {
                TakeHiResShot();
            }
        }

        EditorGUILayout.Space();
        EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();

        if(GUILayout.Button("Open Last Screenshot",GUILayout.MaxWidth(160),GUILayout.MinHeight(40)))
        {
            if(lastScreenshot != "")
            {
                Application.OpenURL("file://" + lastScreenshot);
                Debug.Log("Opening File " + lastScreenshot);
            }
        }

        if(GUILayout.Button("Open Folder",GUILayout.MaxWidth(100),GUILayout.MinHeight(40)))
        {

            Application.OpenURL("file://" + path);
        }

        if(GUILayout.Button("More Assets",GUILayout.MaxWidth(100),GUILayout.MinHeight(40)))
        {
            Application.OpenURL("https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/publisher/5951");
        }

        EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();


        if (takeHiResShot) 
        {
            int resWidthN = resWidth*scale;
            int resHeightN = resHeight*scale;
            RenderTexture rt = new RenderTexture(resWidthN, resHeightN, 24);
            myCamera.targetTexture = rt;

            TextureFormat tFormat;
            if(isTransparent)
                tFormat = TextureFormat.ARGB32;
            else
                tFormat = TextureFormat.RGB24;


            Texture2D screenShot = new Texture2D(resWidthN, resHeightN, tFormat,false);
            myCamera.Render();
            RenderTexture.active = rt;
            screenShot.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, resWidthN, resHeightN), 0, 0);
            myCamera.targetTexture = null;
            RenderTexture.active = null; 
            byte[] bytes = screenShot.EncodeToPNG();
            string filename = ScreenShotName(resWidthN, resHeightN);

            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filename, bytes);
            Debug.Log(string.Format("Took screenshot to: {0}", filename));
            Application.OpenURL(filename);
            takeHiResShot = false;
        }

        EditorGUILayout.HelpBox("In case of any error, make sure you have Unity Pro as the plugin requires Unity Pro to work.",MessageType.Info);


    }



    private bool takeHiResShot = false;
    public string lastScreenshot = "";


    public string ScreenShotName(int width, int height) {

        string strPath="";

        strPath = string.Format("{0}/screen_{1}x{2}_{3}.png", 
                             path, 
                             width, height, 
                                       System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss"));
        lastScreenshot = strPath;

        return strPath;
    }



    public void TakeHiResShot() {
        Debug.Log("Taking Screenshot");
        takeHiResShot = true;
    }

}
```

Camera rotation.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CamRotation_for_camera : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 1;

    void Update()
    {
        transform.Rotate(0, (speed * 5) * Time.deltaTime, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not quite clear whether you want to use this in the editor or on runtime? Do you even need it as EditorWindow if it shall be driven by the camera rotation?

Comment: @derHugo No I don't want it in the editor. I would like it to run from the camera rotation script. I just don't know what code is safe to parse out.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call `Screenshot` from `CamRotation_for_camera` because `Screenshot` is an EditorWindow (to be used by the editor) and `CamRotation_for_camera` is a Monobehaviour (a component for Gameobjects used by the engine). Basically the component has no knowledge of the windows the editor uses.

You can move some of the code for photo-taking into a component though and add that to an object in the scene, then your components will be able to interact.

Eg.

```cs
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;

public class RunTimeScreenshots : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float timeBetweenPhotos = 3;
    private float nextPhotoTime;

    public bool takeScreenshot = false;

    public int resWidth;
    public int resHeight;

    public int scale = 1;

    public bool isTransparent;

    // using a local path here since it's less of a pain to work with
    public string localPath;
    // set up the absolute path here
    private string absolutePath => Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, localPath);

    private string lastScreenshot = "";

    private Camera myCamera;

    void Start()
    {
        myCamera = Camera.main;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // Almost just like the code on Screenshot.OnGUI() but a little different
        // a little bit of timing code for repeated photo-taking
        if (takeScreenshot && Time.time > nextPhotoTime) {
            // make sure to move this forward every time
            nextPhotoTime = Time.time + timeBetweenPhotos;

            int resWidthN = resWidth * scale;
            int resHeightN = resHeight * scale;
            RenderTexture rt = new RenderTexture(resWidthN, resHeightN, 24);
            myCamera.targetTexture = rt;

            TextureFormat tFormat;
            if (isTransparent)
                tFormat = TextureFormat.ARGB32;
            else
                tFormat = TextureFormat.RGB24;


            Texture2D screenShot = new Texture2D(resWidthN, resHeightN, tFormat, false);
            myCamera.Render();
            RenderTexture.active = rt;
            screenShot.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, resWidthN, resHeightN), 0, 0);
            myCamera.targetTexture = null;
            RenderTexture.active = null;
            byte[] bytes = screenShot.EncodeToPNG();
            string filename = ScreenShotName(resWidthN, resHeightN);

            File.WriteAllBytes(filename, bytes);
            Debug.Log(string.Format("Took screenshot to: {0}", filename));
            // we don't open the photo right away since thats a pain,
            // and we aren't going to turn off "takeScreenshot"
        }
    }

    public string ScreenShotName(int width, int height) {

        string strPath = "";

        strPath = string.Format("{0}/screen_{1}x{2}_{3}.png",
                             absolutePath,
                             width, height,
                                       System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss"));
        lastScreenshot = strPath;

        return strPath;
    }
}
```

Set up the component how you'd like and use the `takeScreenshot` checkbox with the game running to turn this on and off.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question. I am having a problem when trying to run the code. #1 Created a folder to match local path #2 I attached the component to my camera GameObject. #3 Ticked Take Screenshot in Run Time Screenshots (Script). This is the error I am getting (NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
RunTimeScreenshots.Update () (at Assets/My Assets/Scripts/RunTimeScreenshots.cs:43)
Thank you for anymore help you can offer!

Comment: Check if the `myCamera` is `null`

Comment: Ofcourse this is now limited to export the pictures to the `dataPath` .. this might fail in a build.

Comment: `Application.dataPath` might fail in a build, I just grabbed it out of the posted Screenshot tool, which only runs in editor.

`myCamera` is being assigned `Camera.main` so if you don't have a camera tagged `main` in your scene, it would be `null` on line 43.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want it to work on runtime you shouldn't use an `EditorWindow` at all.

I would still keep the custom inspector so you can still use it just like before but now as a component attached to a GameObject in the scene:

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
#endif
using UnityEngine;

public class Screenshot : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Vector2Int resolution = new Vector2Int(Screen.width * 4, Screen.height * 4);
    [SerializeField] private Camera _myCamera;
    [SerializeField] [Range(1,15)] private int _scale = 1;
    [SerializeField] private string _path = "";
    [SerializeField] private bool _showPreview = true;
    [SerializeField] private bool _isTransparent = false;
    [SerializeField] private string _lastScreenshot = "";

    private RenderTexture renderTexture;

    private string ScreenShotName(string path, int width, int height) 
    {
        strPath = $"{path}/screen_{width}x{height}_{System.DateTime.Now:yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss}.png";
        _lastScreenshot = strPath;
        return strPath;
    }

    public void TakeScreenshot()
    {
        TakeScreenshot(_myCamera, _resolution, _scale, _path, _isTransparent, _showPreview);
    }

    public void TakeScreenshot(Camera camera, Vector2Int resolution, float scale, string path, bool isTransparent, bool showPreview)
    {
        var finalResolution = resolution * scale;
        if(!renderTexture) renderTexture = new RenderTexture(finalResolution.x, finalResolution.y, 24);
        myCamera.targetTexture = renderTexture;

        var tFormat = isTransparent ? TextureFormat.ARGB32 : TextureFormat.RGB24;

        var screenShot = new Texture2D(finalResolution.x, finalResolution.y, tFormat, false);
        myCamera.Render();
        RenderTexture.active = renderTexture;
        screenShot.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, finalResolution.x, finalResolution.y), 0, 0);
        myCamera.targetTexture = null;
        RenderTexture.active = null; 
        var bytes = screenShot.EncodeToPNG();
        var filename = ScreenShotName(finalResolution.x, finalResolution.y);

        WriteFileAsync(filename, bytes);
    }

    private async void WriteFileAsync(string path, byte[] data)
    {
        using(var file = File.Open(path))
        {
            await file.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        Debug.Log(string.Format("Took screenshot to: {0}", filename));
        if(showPreview) Application.OpenURL(filename);
    }

    #if UNITY_EDITOR
    [CustomEditor(typeof(Screenshot))]
    private class ScreenshotEditor : Editor
    {
        private SerializedProperty resolution;
        private SerializedProperty myCamera;
        private SerializedProperty scale;
        private SerializedProperty path;
        private SerializedProperty showPreview;
        private SerializedProperty isTransparent;
        private SerializedProperty lastScreenshot;

        private void OnEnable()
        {
            resolution = serilaizedObject.FindProperty(nameof((Screenshot._resolution));
            myCamera = serilaizedObject.FindProperty(nameof((Screenshot._myCamera));
            scale = serilaizedObject.FindProperty(nameof((Screenshot._scale));
            path = serilaizedObject.FindProperty(nameof((Screenshot._path));
            showPreview = serilaizedObject.FindProperty(nameof((Screenshot._showPreview));
            isTransparent = serilaizedObject.FindProperty(nameof(Screenshot._isTransparent));
            lastScreenshot = serilaizedObject.FindProperty(nameof(Screenshot._lastScreenshot));
        }

        public override void OnInspectorGUI()
        {
            serializedObject.Update();

            EditorGUI.BeginDisabledGroup(true);
            {
                EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("Script", MonoScript.FromMonoBehaviour((Screenshot)target), typeof(Screenshot), false);
                EditorGUILayout.Space();
            }
            EditorGUI.EndDisabledGroup();

            EditorGUILayout.LabelField ("Resolution", EditorStyles.boldLabel);
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(resolution);
            EditorGUILayout.Space();
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(scale);
            EditorGUILayout.HelpBox("The default mode of screenshot is crop - so choose a proper width and height. The scale is a factor " +
                "to multiply or enlarge the renders without loosing quality.",MessageType.None);

            EditorGUILayout.Space();

            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Save Path", EditorStyles.boldLabel);
            EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
            {
                EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(path, GUILayout.ExpandWidth(false));
                if(GUILayout.Button("Browse",GUILayout.ExpandWidth(false)))
                {
                    path = EditorUtility.SaveFolderPanel("Path to Save Images",path,Application.dataPath);
                }
            } 
            EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
            EditorGUILayout.HelpBox("Choose the folder in which to save the screenshots ",MessageType.None);
            EditorGUILayout.Space();

            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(isTransparent, new GUIContent("Transparent Background"));

            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Select Camera", EditorStyles.boldLabel);
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(myCamera);

            if(!myCamera.objectReferenceValue) myCamera.objectReferenceValue = Camera.main;

            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(isTransparent, new GUIContent("Transparent Background"));
            EditorGUILayout.HelpBox("Choose the camera of which to capture the render. You can make the background transparent using the transparency option.", MessageType.None);
            EditorGUILayout.Space();

            EditorGUILayout.BeginVertical();
            {
                EditorGUILayout.LabelField ("Default Options", EditorStyles.boldLabel);

                if(GUILayout.Button("Set To Screen Size"))
                {
                    resolution.vector2ntValue = new Vector2Int((int)Handles.GetMainGameViewSize().x, (int)Handles.GetMainGameViewSize().y);
                }

                if(GUILayout.Button("Default Size"))
                {
                    resolution.vector2ntValue = new Vector2Int(2560, 1440);
                    scale.intValue = 1;
                }
            }
            EditorGUILayout.EndVertical();

            EditorGUILayout.Space();
            EditorGUILayout.LabelField ("Screenshot will be taken at " + resWidth*scale + " x " + resHeight*scale + " px", EditorStyles.boldLabel);

            if(GUILayout.Button("Take Screenshot", GUILayout.MinHeight(60)))
            {
                if(string.IsNullOrWhitespae(path.stringValue))
                {
                    path.stringValue = EditorUtility.SaveFolderPanel("Path to Save Images", path.stringValue, Application.dataPath);
                    Debug.Log("Path Set");
                    ((Screenshot)target).TakeHiResShot();
                }
                else
                {
                    ((Screenshot)target).TakeHiResShot();
                }
            }

            EditorGUILayout.Space();
            EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();

            if(GUILayout.Button("Open Last Screenshot",GUILayout.MaxWidth(160),GUILayout.MinHeight(40)))
            {
                if(lastScreenshot != "")
                {
                    Application.OpenURL("file://" + lastScreenshot);
                    Debug.Log("Opening File " + lastScreenshot);
                }
            }

            if(GUILayout.Button("Open Folder", GUILayout.MaxWidth(100), GUILayout.MinHeight(40)))
            {
                Application.OpenURL("file://" + path.stringValue);
            }

            if(GUILayout.Button("More Assets", GUILayout.MaxWidth(100), GUILayout.MinHeight(40)))
            {
                Application.OpenURL("https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/publisher/5951");
            }
            EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();

            EditorGUILayout.HelpBox("In case of any error, make sure you have Unity Pro as the plugin requires Unity Pro to work.",MessageType.Info);

            serializedObject.ApplyModiefiedProperties();
        }
    }
#endif
}
```

Then simply attach it to the camera and reference it in your script like

```
public class CamRotation_for_camera : MonoBehaviour
{
    // I would rather not "hide" a secret multiplication by 5 but rather
    // directly assign the correct angle per second here
    [SerializeField] private float speed = 5;
    // hre drag the Screenshot instance
    [SerializeField] private Screenshot screenshot;
    // (estimate) time in seconds between screenshots 
    [SerializedField] private float screenshotInterval;

    private float timer;

    void Update()
    {
        transform.Rotate(0, speed * Time.deltaTime, 0);

        timer += Time.deltaTime;

        if(timer < screenshotInterval) return;

        timer = 0;
        screenshot.TakeScreenshot();
    }
}
```

or alternatively you could go by the rotated angle instead

```
    // (estimate) angle between screenshots 
    [SerializedField] private float screenshotIntervalAngle;

    private float currentAngle;

    void Update()
    {
        var rotationStep = speed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.Rotate(0, rotationStep, 0);

        currentAngle += rotationStep;

        if(currentAngle < screenshotIntervalAngle) return;

        currentAngle = 0;
        screenshot.TakeScreenshot();
    }
```

For both I commented `estimate` in particular for the first. I already moved the File IO to a different thread by using `async` but the most expensive thing is that `EncodeToPNG` which will always create a very noteable lag and wil thereby itself also interfer with the time intervals.

---

*Note: Completely typed on smartphone but I hope the idea gets clear.*